# Find common prefix ends with multiple suffix in python

Tags: python

I have a list of string.

```
A = [
  'kite1.json',
  'kite1.mapping.json',
  'kite1.analyzer.json',
  'kite2.json',
  'kite3.mapping.json',
  'kite3.mapping.mapping.json',
  'kite3.mapping.analyzer.json',
 ]
```

I need to find common prefix which ends with all of `.json`, `.mapping.json`, `.analyzer.json`.

Here, `kite1` & `kite3.mapping` are satisfied. But `kite2` isn't, because it only ends with `.json`.

How can I find those prefix which ends with all of `.json`, `.mapping.json`, `.analyzer.json`.

Comment: does you input should be in the order like above?

Comment: No.. There is no order

Comment: This problem could be easily solved without using regular expressions. What is the reason for the `regex` tag? Is it a requirement?

Comment: No. regular expression is not required. I just choose it

Comment: I modified my question. @soon

Comment: It *could* be make to work to some extent, using regex. depending on some rules. E.g. prefix length min. 5 characters. [See it here](https://regex101.com/r/hG3jO6/1). Remove that rule, and it'll still work, only it'll find `kite` as the common prefix for the last four rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this were [code-golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com), I might win:

```
def ew(sx): 
   return set([s[:-len(sx)] for s in A if s.endswith(sx)])

ew('.analyzer.json') & ew('.mapping.json') & ew('.json')
```

The `ew()` function loops through `A`, finding all elements that end with the given suffix and stripping the suffix off, returning the results at a set.

Using it, I just calculate the intersection of the sets produced from each of the three suffixes. (`&` is the operator for intersection.)

For brevity's sake, I abbreviated "ends with" to `ew` and "suffix" to `sx`.

The expression `s[:-len(sx)]` means "the substring of `s` starting at 0 and going to `len(sx)` characters from the end", which has the effect of the snipping suffix off the end.

Comment: @Keatinge -- of course I can explain it.  I wrote it!

Comment: I wasn't asking if you understood the code you wrote, I was hoping you would include an explanation so me and others could understand how it works. Like an explanation in plain english like "this works because first it does x then it does y". For example what is `:-len(sx)` doing, what is `ew` and `sx` standing for, what are the `&`'s doing.  What does the actual function itself do and why do you call it 3 times? etc etc

Comment: @Keatinge -- I was just teasing you.  Your explanation is in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, all you need is to collect a set of prefixes for each suffix in `['.json', '.mapping.json', '.analyzer.json']` and then just take an intersection of these sets:

```
In [1]: A = [
   ...:   'kite1.json',
   ...:   'kite1.mapping.json',
   ...:   'kite1.analyzer.json',
   ...:   'kite2.json',
   ...:   'kite3.mapping.json',
   ...:   'kite3.mapping.mapping.json',
   ...:   'kite3.mapping.analyzer.json',
   ...:  ]

In [2]: suffixes = ['.json', '.mapping.json', '.analyzer.json']

In [3]: prefixes = {s: set() for s in suffixes}

In [4]: for word in A:
   ....:     for suffix in suffixes:
   ....:         if word.endswith(suffix):
   ....:             prefixes[suffix].add(word[:-len(suffix)])
   ....:             

In [5]: prefixes
Out[5]: 
{'.analyzer.json': {'kite1', 'kite3.mapping'},
 '.json': {'kite1',
  'kite1.analyzer',
  'kite1.mapping',
  'kite2',
  'kite3.mapping',
  'kite3.mapping.analyzer',
  'kite3.mapping.mapping'},
 '.mapping.json': {'kite1', 'kite3', 'kite3.mapping'}}

In [6]: prefixes['.json'] & prefixes['.mapping.json'] & prefixes['.analyzer.json']
Out[6]: {'kite1', 'kite3.mapping'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) and [capturing groups](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) to extract all matches for each of your patterns. Then take the [intersection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) of the resulting sets:

```
import re

s1, s2, s3 = (
    set(m.group(1) for m in (re.match(pattern, s) for s in A) if m) 
    for pattern in (
        r'^(.+)\.json$',          # group(1) is the part within '()'
        r'^(.+)\.mapping\.json$', 
        r'^(.+)\.analyzer\.json$'
    )
)

result = list(s1 & s2 & s3)  # intersection
# ['kite3.mapping', 'kite1']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "\n".join(A)

json_prefices = re.findall(r"(.*?)\.json", string)
mapping_json_prefices = re.findall(r"(.*?)\.mapping\.json", string)
analyzer_json_prefices = re.findall(r"(.*?)\.analyzer\.json", string)

result = list(set(json_prefices) & set(mapping_json_prefices)
               & set(analyzer_json_prefices))
```